# Почему mozilla не показывает альтернативные стили?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, стилизация

Создал html документ

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Стили</title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="style1.css" name="style1">
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Текст про стили</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    color:green;
}
```

**style1.css**

```
body {
    color:yellow;
}
```

Почему в браузере mozilla (Вид-Стиль страницы) нет альтернативного стиля?

Comment: А что тогда это значит в html5? Потому что "alternate stylesheet" также присутствует и в html5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не полностью описаны, правильно так, вместо name - title:

```
  <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Default Style">
  <link href="simple.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Simple">
  <link href="insane.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Insane">
```

Доки и там же демо: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets

Comment: Дописал type="text/css" . Ничего не меняет. В браузере не появляются альтернативные стили

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, не знаю как у вас, но у меня пример из документации по ссылке работает в  FireFox.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев title допиши, итить.

Comment: Точно норм, перепутал атрибуты)

Comment: А как плюс-то поставить?) Что-то не ставится